# using DLL VB6 in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, vb6, windows-mobile, compact-framework, dllimport

How I can use a dll developed in VB6 application on my Windows Mobile 6.5 Compact Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't for a multitude of reasons, including:

- There are no VB6 runtimes for CE
- The DLL is built for the desktop processor/OS architecture

Comment: And you would probably have a hard time registering it.

Comment: Yes, you wouldn't be able to call DllRegisterServer because of #2 above.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done. You'll need to port it to a supported language for that platform.

Comment: There is no problem registering COM libraries in WinMo 6.x.  The problem is they have to be compiled for WinCE 5 on ARM processors, which VB6 cannot do.  A VB6 IDE add-in once supported GUI program development for CE (including ARM) but it produced VBScript "programs" and could not create actual EXEs or COM DLLs.